# Cocoa webview: Slow on first execution of app, then fine

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview, webkit

I have an app that has a webview that works fine in xcode itself, but when I archive the app to the desktop and run it for the first time, it grinds to a halt due to high memory consumption. Something to do with the page it is running. It's only the first time. The page does not create a database or use local storage or anything of the kind. It does do a lot of ajax requests (with tiny responses).

Anyway, this happens every time I archive and then open the app for the first time, but not there after.

Is there any way I can replicate this behavior in xcode? Make it look like it's the first time I'm executing it? Because I do not get this high memory consumption in xcode ever.

Comment: We're having somewhat similar issues. There's a lot of http requests for our app and it all works fine in Safari. When wrapped in WebView, loading is erratically: sometimes it works fine, sometimes in another session it feels around 20 times slower. We were not able to reliably reproduce a clear first-time/ second-time opening difference (though that also sometimes happened). Removing app-sandboxing entitlements -- I had figured that might've throttled it -- didn't help.

Comment: I have exact the same problem! Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for me :)
Set **Optimization Level** for **release build** to **None**. Then do project clean and try again :)

[image: Set Optimization Level to None for Release build]

Comment: Setting optimization level to None is not really a usable solution for production apps